# how to write a process-pool bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, multiprocessing, sh, multiprocess

I have more than 10 tasks to execute, and the system restrict that there at most 4 tasks can run at the same time.

My task can be started like:
myprog taskname

How can I write a bash shell script to run these task. The most important thing is that when one task finish, the script can start another immediately, making the running tasks count remain 4 all the time.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I chanced upon this thread while looking into writing my own process pool and particularly liked Brandon Horsley's solution, though I couldn't get the signals working right, so I took inspiration from Apache and decided to try a pre-fork model with a fifo as my job queue.

The following function is the function that the worker processes run when forked.

```
# \brief the worker function that is called when we fork off worker processes
# \param[in] id  the worker ID
# \param[in] job_queue  the fifo to read jobs from
# \param[in] result_log  the temporary log file to write exit codes to
function _job_pool_worker()
{
    local id=$1
    local job_queue=$2
    local result_log=$3
    local line=

    exec 7<> ${job_queue}
    while [[ "${line}" != "${job_pool_end_of_jobs}" && -e "${job_queue}" ]]; do
        # workers block on the exclusive lock to read the job queue
        flock --exclusive 7
        read line <${job_queue}
        flock --unlock 7
        # the worker should exit if it sees the end-of-job marker or run the
        # job otherwise and save its exit code to the result log.
        if [[ "${line}" == "${job_pool_end_of_jobs}" ]]; then
            # write it one more time for the next sibling so that everyone
            # will know we are exiting.
            echo "${line}" >&7
        else
            _job_pool_echo "### _job_pool_worker-${id}: ${line}"
            # run the job
            { ${line} ; } 
            # now check the exit code and prepend "ERROR" to the result log entry
            # which we will use to count errors and then strip out later.
            local result=$?
            local status=
            if [[ "${result}" != "0" ]]; then
                status=ERROR
            fi  
            # now write the error to the log, making sure multiple processes
            # don't trample over each other.
            exec 8<> ${result_log}
            flock --exclusive 8
            echo "${status}job_pool: exited ${result}: ${line}" >> ${result_log}
            flock --unlock 8
            exec 8>&-
            _job_pool_echo "### _job_pool_worker-${id}: exited ${result}: ${line}"
        fi  
    done
    exec 7>&-
}
```

You can [get a copy of my solution](https://github.com/vtonehundred/shellutils/blob/master/job_pool.sh) at Github.  Here's a sample program using my implementation.

```
#!/bin/bash

. job_pool.sh

function foobar()
{
    # do something
    true
}   

# initialize the job pool to allow 3 parallel jobs and echo commands
job_pool_init 3 0

# run jobs
job_pool_run sleep 1
job_pool_run sleep 2
job_pool_run sleep 3
job_pool_run foobar
job_pool_run foobar
job_pool_run /bin/false

# wait until all jobs complete before continuing
job_pool_wait

# more jobs
job_pool_run /bin/false
job_pool_run sleep 1
job_pool_run sleep 2
job_pool_run foobar

# don't forget to shut down the job pool
job_pool_shutdown

# check the $job_pool_nerrors for the number of jobs that exited non-zero
echo "job_pool_nerrors: ${job_pool_nerrors}"
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 68):

Use `xargs`:

```
xargs -P <maximum-number-of-process-at-a-time> -n <arguments-per-process> <command>
```

Details [here](http://coldattic.info/shvedsky/pro/blogs/a-foo-walks-into-a-bar/posts/7).

Comment: The referred article provides information about "make -j <count>" command also. Good possibility to pool many partially dependent works.

Answer (score 17):

Using GNU Parallel you can do:

```
cat tasks | parallel -j4 myprog
```

If you have 4 cores, you can even just do:

```
cat tasks | parallel myprog
```

From http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README:

#### Full installation

Full installation of GNU Parallel is as simple as:

```
./configure && make && make install
```

#### Personal installation

If you are not root you can add ~/bin to your path and install in
~/bin and ~/share:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME && make && make install
```

Or if your system lacks 'make' you can simply copy src/parallel
src/sem src/niceload src/sql to a dir in your path.

#### Minimal installation

If you just need parallel and do not have 'make' installed (maybe the
system is old or Microsoft Windows):

```
wget http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/plain/src/parallel
chmod 755 parallel
cp parallel sem
mv parallel sem dir-in-your-$PATH/bin/
```

#### Test the installation

After this you should be able to do:

```
parallel -j0 ping -nc 3 ::: foss.org.my gnu.org freenetproject.org
```

This will send 3 ping packets to 3 different hosts in parallel and print
the output when they complete.

Watch the intro video for a quick introduction:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Comment: Oh, that's too much installation details covered in INSTALL

Comment: Thank you Lord for Free Software. Every single thing you need has already been implemented perfectly.

Comment: I just read the manpage of "parallel". It reorders the output, and it even works with remote machines. This thing *ROCKS*.

Comment: Multiple arguments: `seq 100 | parallel echo '{}'`

Comment: You should add some example of use without 'command'. I wasted 5 minutes to find that information in parallel man:
'parallel -j 100 < jobs_to_run.txt' - As there is not a 'command' the jobs will be evaluated by the shell.

Comment: @JerzySBG See: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Working-as-cat-sh.-Resource-inexpensive-jobs-and-evaluation

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest writing four scripts, each one of which executes a certain number of tasks in series. Then write another script that starts the four scripts in parallel. For instance, if you have scripts, script1.sh, script2.sh, script3.sh, and script4.sh, you could have a script called headscript.sh like so.

```
#!/bin/sh
./script1.sh & 
./script2.sh & 
./script3.sh & 
./script4.sh &
```

Comment: That's the simplest solution, but it works best if the workload of the four scripts is roughly the same. In case the job length is unpredictable, two scripts might already be done but the other two might have lots of tasks left. The other solutions redistribute the workload properly.

Answer (score 4):

I found the best solution proposed in [A Foo Walks into a Bar... blog](http://coldattic.info/post/7/) using build-in functionality of well know **xargs** tool
First create a file *commands.txt* with list of commands you want to execute

```
myprog taskname1
myprog taskname2
myprog taskname3
myprog taskname4
...
myprog taskname123
```

and then pipe it to xargs like this to execute in 4 processes pool:

```
cat commands.txt | xargs -I CMD --max-procs=4 bash -c CMD
```

you can modify no of process

Comment: Underrated solution.  I will expand this by noting a commands.txt is not strictly necessary.  I am using it as `for f in $(find ...); do echo "myprog '$f'"; done | xargs...` where myprog operates on a single file.

Answer (score 2):

Following [@Parag Sardas'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19618159/2013580) answer and the documentation linked here's a quick script you might want to add on your `.bash_aliases`.

*Relinking the [doc link](http://coldattic.info/post/7/) because it's worth a read*

```
#!/bin/bash
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/19618159
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/51861820
#
# Example file contents:
# touch /tmp/a.txt
# touch /tmp/b.txt

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ];  then
  echo "$0 <file> [max-procs=0]"
  exit 1
fi

FILE=${1}
MAX_PROCS=${2:-0}
cat $FILE | while read line; do printf "%q\n" "$line"; done | xargs --max-procs=$MAX_PROCS -I CMD bash -c CMD
```

I.e.
`./xargs-parallel.sh jobs.txt 4` maximum of 4 processes read from jobs.txt

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do something clever with signals.

Note this is only to illustrate the concept, and thus not thoroughly tested.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

this_pid="$$"
jobs_running=0
sleep_pid=

# Catch alarm signals to adjust the number of running jobs
trap 'decrement_jobs' SIGALRM

# When a job finishes, decrement the total and kill the sleep process
decrement_jobs()
{
  jobs_running=$(($jobs_running - 1))
  if [ -n "${sleep_pid}" ]
  then
    kill -s SIGKILL "${sleep_pid}"
    sleep_pid=
  fi
}

# Check to see if the max jobs are running, if so sleep until woken
launch_task()
{
  if [ ${jobs_running} -gt 3 ]
  then
    (
      while true
      do
        sleep 999
      done
    ) &
    sleep_pid=$!
    wait ${sleep_pid}
  fi

  # Launch the requested task, signalling the parent upon completion
  (
    "$@"
    kill -s SIGALRM "${this_pid}"
  ) &
  jobs_running=$((${jobs_running} + 1))
}

# Launch all of the tasks, this can be in a loop, etc.
launch_task task1
launch_task tast2
...
launch_task task99
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works, although still some issues on my system.

Comment: @Brandon Horsley Hi, I am getting following error :
 line 37: kill: `': not a pid or valid job spec
In code :
kill -s SIGALRM "${this_pid}"
can you help me why i am getting this ?

Answer (score 1):

This tested script runs 5 jobs at a time and will restart a new job as soon as it does (due to the kill of the sleep 10.9 when we get a SIGCHLD.  A simpler version of this could use direct polling (change the sleep 10.9 to sleep 1 and get rid of the trap).

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

set -o monitor
trap "pkill -P $$ -f 'sleep 10\.9' >&/dev/null" SIGCHLD

totaljobs=15
numjobs=5
worktime=10
curjobs=0
declare -A pidlist

dojob()
{
  slot=$1
  time=$(echo "$RANDOM * 10 / 32768" | bc -l)
  echo Starting job $slot with args $time
  sleep $time &
  pidlist[$slot]=`jobs -p %%`
  curjobs=$(($curjobs + 1))
  totaljobs=$(($totaljobs - 1))
}

# start
while [ $curjobs -lt $numjobs -a $totaljobs -gt 0 ]
 do
  dojob $curjobs
 done

# Poll for jobs to die, restarting while we have them
while [ $totaljobs -gt 0 ]
 do
  for ((i=0;$i < $curjobs;i++))
   do
    if ! kill -0 ${pidlist[$i]} >&/dev/null
     then
      dojob $i
      break
     fi
   done
   sleep 10.9 >&/dev/null
 done
wait
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answer about 4 shell scripts does not fully satisfies me as it assumes that all tasks take approximatelu the same time and because it requires manual set up. But here is how I would improve it.

Main script will create symbolic links to executables following certain namimg convention. For example,

```
ln -s executable1 ./01-task.01
```

first prefix is for sorting and suffix identifies batch (01-04).
Now we spawn 4 shell scripts that would take batch number as input and do something like this

```
for t in $(ls ./*-task.$batch | sort ; do
   t
   rm t
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at my implementation of job pool in bash:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#
# Job pool implementation in BASH
# License: Apache 2.0
#

help() {
    echo
    echo "USAGE: $0 {add|wait} <ID> <limit> <command...>"
    echo
    echo "Where:"
    echo "  <ID>       Job pool identifier"
    echo "  <limit>    Job pool size"
    echo "  <command>  Command to run"
    echo
    exit 1
}

pool_cmd=$1
shift
pool_id=$1
shift

if [ "$pool_cmd" = "add" ]; then
    pool_size=$1
    shift
    if [ -z "$pool_id" ] || [ -z "$pool_size" ] || [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        help
    fi
elif [ "$pool_cmd" = "wait" ]; then
    [ ! -z "$pool_id" ] || help
else
    help
fi

pool_id=$(echo $pool_id | sed 's/\W/_/g')
workdir="/tmp/$(whoami)-jp"
[ -d $workdir ] || mkdir -p $workdir || exit $?
lock_prefix="$workdir/$pool_id"
lock_file="$lock_prefix.$$"

lock() {
    # Critical section:
    (
        flock -x 201 || exit 1

        # Wait for other processes to finish
        num_running=0
        for l in $(eval ls "${lock_prefix}.*" 2>/dev/null); do
            if kill -0 $(echo $l | sed 's/.*\.//'); then
                num_running=$(($num_running+1))
            else
                # Remove lock file for non-existent process
                rm -f $l
            fi
        done

        if [ "$pool_cmd" = "wait" ]; then
            [ $num_running -eq 0 ]
            return $?
        elif [ "$pool_cmd" = "add" ]; then
            if [ $num_running -lt $pool_size ]; then
                touch $lock_file
                return 0
            fi
            return 1
        fi

    ) 201>$workdir/.lock
}

unlock() {
    rm -f $lock_file
}

trap "unlock; exit 0" INT TERM EXIT
```

For example, to run at most 3 processes of cURL when downloading from a lot of URLs, you can wrap your cURL commands as follows:

```
./jp.sh "My Download Pool" 3 curl http://site1/...
./jp.sh "My Download Pool" 3 curl http://site2/...
./jp.sh "My Download Pool" 3 curl http://site3/...
...
```

Comment: Please paste code inside your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. The idea is quite simple. I create a `fifo` as a semaphore, where each line stands for an available resource. When `read`ing the queue, the main process blocks if there is nothing left. And, we return the resource after the task is done by simply `echo`ing anything to the queue.

```sh
function task() {
    local task_no="$1"
    # doing the actual task...
    echo "Executing Task ${task_no}"
    # which takes a long time
    sleep 1
}

function execute_concurrently() {
    local tasks="$1"
    local ps_pool_size="$2"

    # create an anonymous fifo as a Semaphore
    local sema_fifo
    sema_fifo="$(mktemp -u)"
    mkfifo "${sema_fifo}"
    exec 3<>"${sema_fifo}"
    rm -f "${sema_fifo}"

    # every 'x' stands for an available resource
    for i in $(seq 1 "${ps_pool_size}"); do
        echo 'x' >&3
    done

    for task_no in $(seq 1 "${tasks}"); do
        read dummy <&3 # blocks util a resource is available
        (
            trap 'echo x >&3' EXIT # returns the resource on exit
            task "${task_no}"
        )&
    done
    wait # wait util all forked tasks have finished
}

execute_concurrently 10 4
```

The script above will run 10 tasks and 4 each time concurrently. You can change the `$(seq 1 "${tasks}")` sequence to the actual task queue you want to run.

Answer (score 0):

I made my modifications based on methods introduced in this [Writing a process pool in Bash](https://milhouse.dev/2015/11/20/writing-a-process-pool-in-bash/).

```
#!/bin/bash

#set -e   # this doesn't work here for some reason
POOL_SIZE=4   # number of workers running in parallel

#######################################################################
#                            populate jobs                            #
#######################################################################

declare -a jobs

for (( i = 1988; i < 2019; i++ )); do
    jobs+=($i)
done

echo '################################################'
echo '    Launching jobs'
echo '################################################'

parallel() {
    local proc procs jobs cur
    jobs=("$@")         # input jobs array
    declare -a procs=() # processes array
    cur=0               # current job idx

    morework=true
    while $morework; do
        # if process array size < pool size, try forking a new proc
        if [[ "${#procs[@]}" -lt "$POOL_SIZE" ]]; then
            if [[ $cur -lt "${#jobs[@]}" ]]; then
                proc=${jobs[$cur]}
                echo "JOB ID = $cur; JOB = $proc."

                ###############
                # do job here #
                ###############

                sleep 3 &

                # add to current running processes
                procs+=("$!")
                # move to the next job
                ((cur++))
            else
                morework=false
                continue
            fi
        fi

        for n in "${!procs[@]}"; do
            kill -0 "${procs[n]}" 2>/dev/null && continue
            # if process is not running anymore, remove from array
            unset procs[n]
        done
    done
    wait
}

parallel "${jobs[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

xargs with -P and -L options does the job.
You can extract the idea from the example below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

workers_pool_size=10

set -e

function doit {
    cmds=""
    for e in 4 8 16; do
        for m in 1 2 3 4 5 6; do
            cmd="python3 ./doit.py --m $m -e $e -m $m"
            cmds="$cmd\n$cmds"
        done
    done
    echo -e "All commands:\n$cmds"
    echo "Workers pool size = $workers_pool_size"
    echo -e "$cmds" | xargs -t -P $workers_pool_size -L 1 time > /dev/null
}

doit
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/bash
doSomething() {
    <...>
}

getCompletedThreads() {
    _runningThreads=("$@")

    removableThreads=()
    for pid in "${_runningThreads[@]}"; do
        if ! ps -p $pid > /dev/null; then
            removableThreads+=($pid)
        fi
    done
    echo "$removableThreads"
}

releasePool() {
    while [[ ${#runningThreads[@]} -eq $MAX_THREAD_NO ]]; do
        echo "releasing"
        removableThreads=( $(getCompletedThreads "${runningThreads[@]}") )
        if [ ${#removableThreads[@]} -eq 0 ]; then
            sleep 0.2
        else
            for removableThread in "${removableThreads[@]}"; do
                runningThreads=( ${runningThreads[@]/$removableThread} ) 
            done
            echo "released"
        fi
    done
}

waitAllThreadComplete() {
    while [[ ${#runningThreads[@]} -ne 0 ]]; do
        removableThreads=( $(getCompletedThreads "${runningThreads[@]}") )
        for removableThread in "${removableThreads[@]}"; do
            runningThreads=( ${runningThreads[@]/$removableThread} ) 
        done

        if [ ${#removableThreads[@]} -eq 0 ]; then
            sleep 0.2
        fi
    done
}


MAX_THREAD_NO=10
runningThreads=()
sequenceNo=0

for i in {1..36}; do
    releasePool

    ((sequenceNo++))
    echo "added $sequenceNo"
    doSomething &

    pid=$!
    runningThreads+=($pid)
done

waitAllThreadComplete
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.