# How to know if a background jobs are finished in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

How to know if a background jobs are finished in shell script?

```
n=0
while [ $n le 10 ]
do 
dosomething &
n= `expr $n + 1`
done
```

how can we know all dosomething processes completed or not?

after completion i want to print `echo "done"`

Comment: Use the bash builtin named... surprise... `wait`. Perhaps also `jobs`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `wait`, like so:

```
n=0
while [ $n le 10 ]
do 
  dosomething &
done
wait
# all dosomething are finished here
```

If you will need to wait for just a few of them you could use `wait $pid`, to wait for a specific pid, which you get by executing `$!`, which means give me the pid of the last command.

EDIT:

I've seen that there are two questions on the matter, have a look at them:

- [How to wait in bash for several subprocesses to finish and return exit code !=0 when any subprocess ends with code !=0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356100/how-to-wait-in-bash-for-several-subprocesses-to-finish-and-return-exit-code-0)
- [Waiting for background processes to finish before exiting script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254118/waiting-for-background-processes-to-finish-before-exiting-script)

the second of which seems exactly a copy of your question, I'm voting to close this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
for i in {1..10}; do 
    command &
done; wait
```

It gets slightly shorter using the `for` loop and a range of numbers.

Comment: But it does something different. The OP example runs 10 subtasks *in parallel*. Yours does them one after another. (`in {1..10}` is better than OP, though.)

Comment: @rici Good point, I'll change it back.