# How to determine the execution stop event of a program

Tags: unix, sh

I have a script which logs certain data when a benchmark (some c code like matrix multiplication) runs.

I want to first start the log script when benchmark starts, this is easy since I can just start the binary from the log script and then proceed to log the info.

But the real question is when do I stop it? The benchmark can stop at anytime (The log script shouldn't stop the benchmark). How do I get the info/variable which can be used in the log script to stop it when benchmark program stops?

I was thinking if I can use PID of the benchmark, but then thought there should be a better solution than searching and using the PID.

Thanks!

Comment: How does your log script get the data to log? Maybe you could use  something like: _"if there's no more data to log, then exit script"_

Comment: That is a really good question. The log data is the temperature and other parameters which are always present, due to benchmark, they will change. I want to log this change when benchmark runs. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: Have you tried this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254118/waiting-for-background-processes-to-finish-before-exiting-script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254118/waiting-for-background-processes-to-finish-before-exiting-script) ?

Comment: No, as soon as I go through that  link, I will summarize it in this thread. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Your main script
#

# Run your log program in background
your_log_program &

# The PID of last background program
LOGPROGRAMPID=$!

# Install EXIT trap  (EXIT is a bash's special event)
trap 'kill -15 $LOGPROGRAMPID; exit 0' EXIT
# In foreground launch your benchmark program
run_your_benchmark_program

# When benchmark program ends your trap will be launched and it will kill your log
# program.
```