# tshark Packet Capture Count is Wrong

Tags: bash, networking, wireshark, tshark

When I run the Bash shell script below, the last line reports anywhere from 4 - 9 packets captured when it should report 29 - 34 packets captured, and it says "tshark: "RESULTS/C6-1/C6-1n10.pcap" appears to have been cut short in the middle of a packet."

If I run the tshark command embedded in the last line of this script from the command line after the scripts exits, the count is correct.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

tshark -i eth1 -a duration:245 -w RESULTS/C6-1/C6-1n10.pcap &> /dev/null &

# tshark seems to take some time to start. Allow for this.
sleep 10

# This takes 225 seconds to run.
mgen flush input C6-1/C6-1n10.mgn 2>&1 | tee RESULTS/C6-1/C6-1n10_mgen_log.txt

mgen_stats RESULTS/C6-1/C6-1n10_mgen_log.txt 20 20 224 20 239 60 2>&1 | tee RESULTS/C6-1/C6-1n10_mgen_analysis.txt

echo 2>&1 | tee -a RESULTS/C6-1/C6-1n10_mgen_analysis.txt
echo 2>&1 | tee -a RESULTS/C6-1/C6-1n10_mgen_analysis.txt
echo 2>&1 | tee -a RESULTS/C6-1/C6-1n10_mgen_analysis.txt

echo "There should be 29 - 34 messages from group 239.0.20.20. The actual count is:" 2>&1 | tee -a RESULTS/C6-1/C6-1n10_mgen_analysis.txt

# Ensure that the tshark instance we started above has time to exit before we start another instance.
sleep 20

echo `tshark -r RESULTS/C6-1/C6-1n10.pcap -R "ip.src == 104.4.20.2 && ip.dst == 239.0.20.20" | wc -l` 2>&1 | tee -a RESULTS/C6-1/C6-1n10_mgen_analysis.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no guarantees that the initial tshark instance has actually finished by that point. Rather than guessing at times and using sleep, use `wait` instead to force the script to wait for tshark to finish.

[Waiting for background processes to finish before exiting script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254118/waiting-for-background-processes-to-finish-before-exiting-script)

Answer (score 0):

1. Inappropriate packet count is returned when we use “wc -l” in tshark filter in TShark 1.12.1 version (working fine in TShark 1.10.1)
2. issue seen when we filter pcap file with "(ipv6.nxt ==17)" field in TShark 1.12.1 version (working fine in TShark 1.10.1)