# Linux - Shell script run curl command in parallel

Tags: linux, shell

I would like to create linux shell script to run CURL command in parallel

For example: I have three command like

1. curl -s http://localhost/process.php?id=1
2. curl -s http://localhost/process.php?id=2
3. curl -s http://localhost/process.php?id=3

I want to call above three command simultaneously.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just connect the commands by `&`.

Comment: just add '&' to the end of your command, you can reference here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338870/what-does-at-the-end-of-a-linux-command-mean

Comment: Thank you very much. Working as expected.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think a bash script like:

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -s http://localhost/process.php?id=1 &
curl -s http://localhost/process.php?id=2 &
curl -s http://localhost/process.php?id=3 &
```

However, this is starting all tasks as background processes.
Don't know how crucial simultaneous starting of the process is.

Comment: FWIW this was enough for me. The two requests were logged as happened in the same millisecond.

Comment: Is there any way to wait for them all to finish?

Comment: Yes.... see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254118/waiting-for-background-processes-to-finish-before-exiting-script

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use & in between the curl commands in a single line like this:

```
curl -s http://localhost/process.php?id=1 & curl -s http://localhost/process.php?id=2 & curl -s http://localhost/process.php?id=3
```