# Running .jar file multiple times

Tags: java, bash, sparql, rdf

So I run the bash script below:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /data/www/usr/rzzw/todo/
for i in *; do
    endpoint=$(less $i | sed -rn 's/(.*\|endpoint - )(.*)/\2/p')
    nohup java -jar /data/www/usr/rzzw/sum/file.jar /data/www/usr/rzzw/sum/config.properties $endpoint 1>"../done/$i-out" 2>"../done/err/$i-err" &
done
```

It works fine, creates logs and executes jar file X times. Thats exactly what i wanted. The jar file starts getting informations about SPARQL endpoint.

But at the beginning this file has to do a complicated SPARQL select which sametimes may take a lot of time. During waiting for a response "something" kills these processes. I was expecting that **nohup** is gonna take care about background process **&**.

STDERR:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
```

This error happens only when commands are being done by script. When I try it in Linux terminal by myself there are no errors.

Example of working command:

```
nohup java -jar /data/www/usr/rzzw/sum/file.jar /data/www/usr/rzzw/sum/config.properties data.archiveshub.ac.uk/sparql 1>out 2>err &
```

Is there any other solution for running -jar file multiple times or can somehow this bash script wait until it responses?

I didnt create this -jar file and everything that happens during its execution is written just in command line.

Comment: Yes I mean Linux terminal, sorry about that. Command: nohup java -jar /data/www/usr/rzzw/sum/file.jar /data/www/usr/rzzw/sum/config.properties http://data.archiveshub.ac.uk/sparql 1>out 2>err &

Comment: The post is edited, hope it's clear now :)

Comment: Try adding `wait` to have processes finish: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14254118/1422451